# Which is better "nested if" or "if and multiple else if"?

Tags: if-statement, optimization

Which code snippet has better performance?

Assuming that 'a' and 'b' are boolean variables.

First Code Snippet

```java
if (a && b) {
    // path 1
} else if (a) {
    // path 2
} else if (b) {
    // path 3
} else {
    // path 4
}
```

Second Code Snippet

```java
if (a) {
    if (b) {
        // path 1
    } else {
        // path 2
    }
} else {
    if (b) {
        // path 3
    } else {
        // path 4
    }
}
```

It seems that the second code snippet is doing less work but I don't know if nesting 'if conditions' have side-effects.

Comment: Just do a loop 1 to 10 million and time it using one 'if' strategy then the other - you will have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid nesting until it’s necessary. Having a deep syntax tree increase chance of failure. In general these operators you present won’t pose a performance issue unless overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

> Which code snippet has better performance?

Ideally; the performance of both snippets will be identical because the compiler will optimize whatever you write into whichever form is fastest for the specific computer it's being compiled for. In this case, whichever is better is whichever is easier to read and maintain.

Note that (if performance isn't the same due to compiler's optimizer) the specific computer it's compiled for may be completely different to the computer you use; and benchmarking it can also give you results that are wrong for other usages on the same computer (e.g. if the branches are predictable by the CPU in the benchmark but not predictable in normal usage outside the benchmark, then results from the benchmark will not be indicative of performance outside the benchamrk). In other words; (if performance isn't the same due to compiler's optimizer) **there's no guarantee that benchmarking the performance will tell you anything useful about performance**.